# Django shuts down after pandas DataFrame.loc search by index and column combination returns KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, django, pandas, dataframe, crash

I am using pandas to read csv and create Dataframe with columns pilot and avarage_lap_time. So to do find average_lap_time for particular pilot I use:

```
for pilot in race_statistic_df.loc[:, "pilot"]:
    needed_index = race_statistic_df.loc[race_statistic_df.loc[:, "pilot"] == pilot, "pilot"].index
    lap_time = race_statistic_df.loc[
        needed_index,
        "average_lap_time"
    ]
```

As soon, as my programme tries to do `lap_time =` django stopps working, without any arrors printed into console. Also wants to mention, for some reason just doing `needed_index =` is fine, but as soon as it goes into `lap_time =` - crash appears

I am trying to get value from Dataframe by the combination of Int64Index and column name with function pd.Dataframe.loc

Answer (score 0):

My file has avArage_lap_time column, and I am trying to search for avErage_lap_time. So server receives KeyError and shut down immediately. So looks like it is a bug with Django itself because, it only replicates when I try to search by the Int64Index. When server uses Int element - it's alright, error prints into console and everything is clear.